# What's the use of ParentNode.append() if there already is Node.appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, w3c

`ParentNode.append()`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append), [W3C Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-append)

`Node.appendChild()`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [W3C Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild)

Both methods seem to do the same thing. What's the use of having both?

Comment: Did you read `Differences to Node.appendChild():` from MDN link for `append()` ?

Comment: @MysterX Hard to believe, but I didn't notice it :P.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is answered in the [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) you posted.

> Differences to Node.appendChild():
>
> - ParentNode.append() allows you to also append DOMString object, whereas Node.appendChild() only accepts Node objects.
> - ParentNode.append() has no return value, whereas Node.appendChild() returns the appended Node object.
> - ParentNode.append() can append several nodes and strings, whereas Node.appendChild() can only append one node.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the conclutions of the MDN difference setion in the article cited above are:

- You dont need to create a node with document.createTextNode("some text") and then append it to an element. You do those things in one step, just appending it with append("some text").
- You can add several elements in one step also. Something very usefull when creating groups of element that are generated simultaneusly  when creating genereting content dinamically.

NOTE: take into consideration that append() is not supported by IE